# How to read file char by char and get total data using node.js?

Tags: node.js

I need to read a char to char and get all your data file and stop when you find a "\ n", any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use [fs.ReadStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_readstream):

```
const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filename, {
    encoding: 'utf8',
    fd: null,
});

readStream.on('readable', () => {
    let char;
    while((char = readStream.read(1)) != null && char != '\n') {
        //use char
    }
})
```